# Why didn’t Theodore Roethke serve in WW2?

Tags: theodore-roethke

Why didn’t Theodore Roethke serve in WW2? He should have been in his mid 30s during WW2, but I can’t find any references to his service (or lack of service). Anyone know?

Answer (score 2):

I can't find anything definitive online, but I wonder if his history of mental illness had something to do with it. The timeline isn't totally clear from [this short bio on the Poetry Foundation website](https://www.poetryfoundation.org/poets/theodore-roethke) and [this one on Biography](https://www.biography.com/people/theodore-roethke-40275), but sometime before the U.S. entered WW2 Roethke had suffered a series of mental breakdowns severe enough that he had needed to be admitted to a sanitarium. Looking at some historical data ([this study, for instance](http://history.amedd.army.mil/booksdocs/wwii/NeuropsychiatryinWWIIVolI/appendixa.htm)) draftees could be disqualified for mental illnesses like manic depression. Perhaps this disqualified Roethke from military service.